# Access SQL server using C# with generic credentials

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a generic user (username:user and password:user) that has access to my SQL Database.
So, if I use the following code, I can access to it without problems:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    Class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string conString = "Data source=server; Initial catalog=db; Integrated security=true";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString);
            using (conn)
            {
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table", conn);
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

However, if I change the conString by replacing `IntegratedSecurity=true` by `User ID=user; Password=user`, then I have the exception

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:'Login failed for user 'user'.'
```

I would like to hardcode those credentials so every user without access to the database may use those generic credentials, but I cannot solve that exception.

Comment: If you turn off integrated security then it stops using windows credentials and instead you have to set up a specific user account within SQL Server itself.

Comment: Ps. To be clear, you _can't_ use integrated security to login as a different windows user than the one the code is running under (just in case that's what you're hoping)

Comment: Hi. Yes, that's why I'm replacing IntegratedSecurity=true by specific generic credentials. However, when I turn off the integrated security and I type in the user credentials I get that exception.

Comment: Well then you need to check the user details are correct in the SQL Server and match what you're providing. Did you create a SQL Server user ?

Comment: When I log into windows I type Username: _user_ and password: _user_
With integrated security I'm taking for granted that those are the credentials used. But if I type those, I get the error.
Is there a way to check what are the credentials passed when using integrated security?

Comment: Ok so you're saying that's a Windows username you're specifying in the connection string, rather than a SQL user? Please read my second comment again. Especially the bit where it says "can't". If you turn integrated security off, then you must log in as a SQL user, not a Windows user. So your goal is easy to achieve - just create a SQL user with suitable credentials.

Comment: How can it be not created if it can access using integrated security?

Comment: ??? . I'll try to explain one more time: You have turned off integrated security in your connection string. When you turn off integrated security, then to log in successfully you must provide the credentials of a **SQL Server user**, _not_ a Windows user. Therefore, before you start you must go to SQL Server and create a suitable login, and give it the permissions it needs. If you're using SSMS, go to your server, go to Security, right-click on "Logins" and click "New Login". In the box which appears, select the "SQL Server authentication" radio button and create your user.

Comment: You can only log into SQL Server using a Windows user when you are using Integrated Security. When you are using Integrated Security you can only log in as the same Windows user which is running the code. The code will automatically send your credentials to SQL. You **cannot** specify a username and password specifically when using Integrated Security (either your own, or another account). And when you aren't using Integrated Security, you can't use a Windows login.

Comment: Do you understand now?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but I already have that. I'll illustrate it, just in case I'm missing something:
The user exists in the server: [link](https://i.imgur.com/yrVx4c2.png)
The user has the right accesses: [link](https://i.imgur.com/Bfwtmmc.png)
Still the code doesn't work: [link](https://i.imgur.com/CesR7fx.png)

Comment: @PabloD., you need to 1) create a SQL Login for your generic user, 2) grant user access to the database, and 3) grant permissions to the user your application code needs. For example `CREATE LOGIN YourUser WITH PASSWORD='YourUserP@assw0rd;USE db;CREATE USER YourUser;GRANT SELECT ON dbo.YourTable to YourUser;'`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I already have it! But it still doesn't work

Comment: @PabloD. Can you connect SSMS with the SQL user name and password?

Comment: Some visual hints here: https://www.guru99.com/sql-server-create-user.html

Comment: @PabloD., make sure the server is configured to allow SQL authentication (Windows only is the default). Check the SQL Server error log as that will have more detail as to why the login failed.

Comment: Thanks, @Arvo . That tutorial really helped!

Comment: Integrated Security = true uses windows credentials of the user who is logged in.  So you never use both Integrate Security = true AND a username/password.